# How to debug a TSQL in VISUAL STUDIO 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql

I am trying to debug a TSQL via Visual Studio 2005. I added the database connection and are now able to connect. But I initially I couldn't see the "Attach To Process" under tools. I went into the customize option and drag and dropped the "Attach To Process" under tools. Now I can see the "Attach To Process" under tools, but it is disabled.

Can someone please let me know how to enable this and debug a TSQL?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it (including Walkthroughs):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165045%28VS.80%29.aspx

Another great walkthrough:
http://odetocode.com/Articles/425.aspx

If even after this you get struck, check this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/2c4e7633-fd99-4e53-b89f-26f6b46c914c

**Note**: Depending on the SQL Server versions you might not be able to debug in VS 2005. Check the last link for this.